# Xamarin Forms Search Bar padding

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using the built in searchbar control in xamarin forms. It works fine for my implementation but I notice there is a small amount of whitespace on each side of the control. I see that i can modify margin to 0 but it does not change the whitespace. Here is what it looks like with a picker above it and a map below it:

[image: search bar]

Here is my xaml

```
    <Picker x:Name="servicePicker" Title="Test" ios:Picker.UpdateMode="Immediately"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">

    </Picker>
     <SearchBar Margin="0" Placeholder="Enter a zip code" TextChanged="Handle_TextChanged"></SearchBar>
        <maps:Map Margin="0"
        x:Name="MyMap"
        IsShowingUser="true"
        MapType="Hybrid"
    />
</StackLayout>
```

I dont see any option for padding, how can i get rid of the whitespace?

Comment: You mean the gray background?

Comment: No the white space above and below the grey bar. There appears to be some padding to the search bar control

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe try setting your stacklayout spacing to zero?

```
<StackLayout Spacing="0">
    ...
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: Bingo that worked, such an easy solution thanks a lot!